# Spritebatch removing front faces of Cubes

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

[image: Picture showing the issue]

Not much more i can do to explain the issue.

Heres my main draw method.
If I change the

```
controls.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
spriteBatch.Begin();
```

to

```
controls.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs);
```

The blocks draw perfectly, except no controls or text is drawn on the screen.

```
d = new DepthStencilState(); //Class level
d.DepthBufferEnable = true;
d.DepthBufferWriteEnable = true;            
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = d;
rs = RasterizerState.CullNone;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Cyan);

    // need to do this on reach devices to allow non 2^n textures
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp; 
    //spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs);

    if (gameState == State.BREAKOUT)
    {
        wallBlock.Draw(camera);

        if (firstBlocks.Count < 49)
        {
            foreach (Block block in secondBlocks)
            {
               block.Draw(camera);
            }
        }

        foreach (Block block in firstBlocks)
        {
            block.Draw(camera);
        }

        ball.Draw(GraphicsDevice, camera.View, camera.Projection, spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs); 
        controls.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        if (ball.scoreMultiplier <= 1)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                       scoreFont, 
                       "Score: " + 
                       scoreDiff + 
                       "\n Lives:" + 
                       ball.lives, 
                       new Vector2(100, 10), 
                       Color.Black);
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                       scoreFont, 
                       "Score: " + 
                       scoreDiff + 
                       "x" + 
                       ball.scoreMultiplier + 
                       " multiplier!" + 
                       "\n Lives:" 
                       + ball.lives, 
                       new Vector2(100, 10), 
                       Color.Black);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with SpriteSortModes? (Can't help anymore right now sorry!) you may find more luck over at gamedev.stackexchange

Comment: Just tried all of them, none of them changed whats being drawn to the screen

Comment: The only other thing I would try is to move the text draw code ahead of the controls

Comment: This resulted in the blocks being drawn perfectly, the text being drawn, but the controls are not drawn at all.

Comment: controls might be behind the blocks then (I'm trying to say I think its drawing them in the order they are in the method)

Comment: I've tried almost every order for them, and cant find one that works. This code works perfectly on Windows Phone, its just having issues with monogame and Windows 8..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the winding order of the faces of your boxes is backwards.  Calling the default `SpriteBatch.Begin()` method resets the device's cull mode to `CullCounterClockwiseFace`.

When you change the call to this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs);
```

...it's overriding that default and setting the device to `CullNone`.  You don't necessarily need to use `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`, but if your boxes have the wrong winding order you will need to specify a non-default `RasterizerState`.

As to why this works on some platforms but not others, I can't say.  You've run into the fact that [all abstractions are leaky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).  MonoGame is implemented on top of OpenGL on most platforms, so what's going on under the covers is fundamentally different.

In general, when you're trying to be cross-platform, it's better to be *specific* about what you're doing—in this case, by manually specifying the device states in `SpriteBatch.Begin()`—because it gives the implementation more information about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: When I put the controls and text drawing code in the spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs); , neither the controls or text is being drawn. Changing RasterizeState does effect how the cubes are drawn, but none of the options end with the text, the controls and the cubes being drawn properly.

Comment: That's probably because you're also turning on depth reads (the `d` in this call), which you almost certainly don't want for UI elements.  What you should probably do is use the default states for UI rendering, but manually specify the rasterizer state prior to rendering the cubes.  That is, right after the line that sets `GraphicsDevice.SamplerState[0]`, add another line that sets `GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState` to one with the appropriate cull mode.

Comment: @user2618681, you should mark this as the answer if it answered your question so that others with the same question will see this one has an answer if they search for their question...not to mention people will probably be more likely to help you if you mark answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Cyan);
```

it before spriteBtach

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Cyan);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, d, rs); 
controls.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: This results in none of the blocks, or the ball being drawn.